# What Icon Style Would Be Better

Tags: website-design, css, ios

I am creating an educational app that looks similar to an iPhone app using the default web stack composed of HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript. I am wondering if it would be more user friendly/motivational to have awards like Apprentice/Expert or awards like Ruby/Diamond/Gold/Silver/Platinum based on the amount of practicing they have done ? I am also making iOS homescreen icons for these awards because they are displayed on a web page that looks like the iPhone homescreen, so which would be more practical and would be easier to understand ? I just want to know what would would transfer a better motivational/inspirational effect, as this website is aimed at kids/teens.

Comment: While we do allow certain subjective questions here, I think this one is a little _too_ subjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either would be fine depending on how they are visually represented. For example if you do apprentice/expert having a character pop up that looks a little more epic at each stage would be great for young people and easily understood. With the stones/gold, silver etc. some sort of means of measuring the value of each stage would be great. At the risk of sounding a little childish I'm going to reference Pokemon black. Each time you earn a badge its shown in your badge case alongside any other badges that you've won as well as empty space, or a dark shape where you still need to earn badges.  If there are only a small amount of stages I would suggest the apprentice/expert idea. If there are going to be many I suggest the ruby/gold reward system. Both are suitable from my interpretation of the project, it's the manner in which they are awarded and display the progress that makes it simple to understand.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, that really helps because my friends and I were coming up this as a side project, as we are all 12 years old, and therefore, all our opinions are biassed. I think I will go with the materials though, because as you said, it will look better when there are many stages as I will have ~20 - 30 hopefully because its easier to get teens to try new things when there is an easier chance to advance to the next level while still being educational. Hopefully, I can get a good business with this idea, as I'm designing database right now, making images, and making games to motivate people to learn